# Gatsby: Event Listeners not unmounting on React useEffects hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I am using Gatsby.

I have this useEffect() hook that adds and removes Event Listeners to the document so I can track outside clicks to close the respective menus. But when I navigate to another route and open my menu, the app breaks and I get this error:

```
header.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null
    at handleDropdown (header.js:121)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (header.js:134)
```

I get this error thrice on every click anywhere as I have three event listeners. I added a console log and realized that during route change, for a moment, the values of the refs go to null. I feel the issue is because the header.js unmounts and then remounts. But I have added a return to the useEffect hook, that should remove the event listener and add them back when the new route loads. Have I done something wrong above?

Below is my my function and the useEffect hook.

```
// Function to close menus on outside clicks
  const handleDropdown = (menuRef, buttonRef, handler, e) => {
    console.log(!!menuRef.current, !!buttonRef.current)

    if (
      menuRef.current.contains(e.target) ||
      buttonRef.current.contains(e.target)
    ) {
      return
    }

    handler(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", e =>
      handleDropdown(mobileMenuRef, menuButtonRef, setShowMobileMenu, e)
    )

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", e =>
      handleDropdown(coursesMenuRef, coursesButtonRef, setShowCoursesMenu, e)
    )

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", e =>
      handleDropdown(
        schedulesMenuRef,
        schedulesButtonRef,
        setShowSchedulesMenu,
        e
      )
    )

    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleFixedNavbar)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", e =>
        handleDropdown(mobileMenuRef, menuButtonRef, setShowMobileMenu, e)
      )

      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", e =>
        handleDropdown(coursesMenuRef, coursesButtonRef, setShowCoursesMenu, e)
      )

      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", e =>
        handleDropdown(
          schedulesMenuRef,
          schedulesButtonRef,
          setShowSchedulesMenu,
          e
        )
      )

      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleFixedNavbar)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are compared by reference. That means `() => {} !== () => {}`. When you try to remove the event listeners in your `useEffect` cleanup callback you pass newly defined functions, but because of the above they won't match the existing handlers that you defined.

If you refactor your code to include the event handler in the `useEffect` hook you can pass the same hook-local variable to both `(add|remove)EventListener` calls:

```
const useOnClickOutside = (refs, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventHandler = e => {
      if (refs.some(ref => ref.current.contains(e.target))) {
        return
      } else {
        callback(false)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", eventHandler)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", eventHandler)
    }
  }, [refs, callback])
}

const YourComponent = () => {
  const someRef = useRef()
  const someOtherRef = useRef()
  useOnClickOutside([someRef, someOtherRef], () => {
    console.log("Click outside happened!")
  })

  return <div>Some Content</div>
}
```

Comment: Perfection! Thanks Corey. This worked like a charm. Learn something new about functions compared as references. Thanks again :)